How do I declare a numpy array to be 1 dimensional of arbitrary length?
I am working on a python code base and the team has decided to make everything statically typed.
I want to declare a numpy array of floats to be one dimension, with arbitrary length.
I currently have the following:
float64 = np.dtype[np.float64]
floats = np.ndarray[Any, float64]

What exactly is the role of Any in this case? Does this declaration permit multi-dimensional arrays? How do I statically differentiate between 1, 2, or 3 dimensional arrays?

Python of course is not a statically typed language, despite your team decision. And in many statically typed languages, array bounds are part of the array type. So what sort of Python dialect has your team invented? The question makes it appear as if your team decided to have arrays with fixed length, as usual. In that case, that's your team decision and you need to argue with them.

@MSalters unfortunately I have already lost the argument ;) at least for now. Also, many languages have things like vectors which are like automatically resizing arrays. The team has decided to have arrays of fixed dimension, not fixed size. I think the question is answerable, but it may be that the answer is: python does not support this.

See also the answers to this related question, in particular the first one. To summarize this first answer: It seems like, as of today, Any is a placeholder for future shape annotation possibilities. These possibilites, however, have not been implemented, yet – see corresponding issue on GitHub.

@simon, this seems like the correct answer. If you would like to elevate your comment to an answer I will accept it. Or I suppose we could close this as a duplicate?

@ChechyLevas It's not exactly a duplicate, as the linked question not really deals with typing shape information (there, it is just a "by-product"). I will make it an answer then. In any case: glad I could help you!

I updated my original answer in light of the changes regarding array typing with NumPy 2.1.0.

Update: With the release of NumPy 2.1.0, the shape in typing an array has now been restricted to be a tuple of int (see release notes) and thus matches what has been suggested in Don't write to me 10am-6pm's answer.
This means that writing something like
a1d: np.ndarray[tuple[int], np.float64]

should now indeed be the way to declare a 1-dimensional array (the code change of the pull request contains a corresponding test case for 2-dimensional arrays). Support in IDEs and typecheckers, for now, still seems to be lacking though – see, for example, this answer to a related question.
Original answer: As of today, it seems like there is no support for shape hints in Numpy, yet – the corresponding issue is still open.
In this context, Any seems to be used as a placeholder for forward compatibility with future shape annotation capabilities – see also this answer to a related question and the comments to the answer.
For the time being and for the sake of legibility, maybe the numpy.typing.NDArray alias is the better candidate for annotating arrays. In particular, it omits Any. Furthermore, the answers to the related question also suggest the (3rd-party) nptyping package. I have no experience with its use, but it might be worth a look, as well.

For a less verbose syntax, you could use the lightweight optype library (I'm the author).
import numpy as np
from optype.numpy import Array

Array_1d_f8: Array[tuple[int], np.float64]
Array_1d_any: Array[tuple[int]]   # defaults to `np.generic`

Or in case you're doing something with broadcasting, you could use e.g. optype.numpy.AtLeast1D to type Array[AtLeast1D, np.float64], which, as the name suggests, describes an array that has len(shape) == ndim >= 1.
For more info, see the docs.

To statically differentiate between different dimensional arrays, you can use tuples to specify the shape:
1D array: `np.ndarray[Tuple[int], np.float64]
2D array: `np.ndarray[Tuple[int, int], np.float64]`
3D array: `np.ndarray[Tuple[int, int, int], np.float64]`

Here is sample code:
from typing import Tuple
import numpy as np

# One-dimensional array
array1d: np.ndarray[Tuple[int], np.float64] = np.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0])

# Two-dimensional array
array2d: np.ndarray[Tuple[int, int], np.float64] = np.array([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 
4.0]])

# Three-dimensional array
array3d: np.ndarray[Tuple[int, int, int], np.float64] = np.array([[[1.0], 
[2.0]], [[3.0], [4.0]]])


This doesn't look right to me. Do you have a reference? What is the role of "int" in your sample code?
